# jquery-validation plug-in import for jasmine testing

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, jasmine, jquery-validate

I am trying to write test cases using jasmine for a javascript page with jquery-validation plug-in.
I am getting the below error , when I run the jasmine test in then node environment.

TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function

Jquery validation plug-in  https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Looks like , the jquery validation plug-in js is not imported into jasmine . 
Please let me know how to import any plug-in js in jasmine which is running under node environment.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install jQuery module?

```
npm install jquery
```

From https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery:

To make jQuery work in Node, a window with a document is required. Since no such window exists natively in Node (nor in Jasmine), one can be mocked by tools such as [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom).

```
require("jsdom").env("", function(err, window) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }

    var $ = require("jquery")(window);
});
```

Comment: @ Joachim , I have included jquery as you mentioned above. I am able to access jquery but not the jquery-validation plugin method.

Comment: But you are sure you `require`d it after jQuery?

Comment: Yes . I did the same but still it is having the same issue.

Comment: Can you provide a litte more code context? I think this must have something to do with the order of requires or functional scopes.